# Create Custom touch action for Navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Navigation drawer in android has 3 behaviors

```
  - Always opened, and can be close only programming using LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN.
  - Always closed, and can be open only  programming LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED.
  - User can open and close the drawer. using LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED
```

The third one will be closed automatically if user click out side the drawer when it is open. While the first one will remain always open.

```
I need to have custom one that user can open and close the drawer, and when he clicks outside the drawer it will remains open.
```

I was thinking for overriding onInterceptTouchEvent.

Any one did something similer?

/*********ADED***********
I extended the DrawerLayout , and it works not sure yet if 100%

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
  Context ccontext;
  public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context) {
      this(context, null);
  }

public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)      {
 super(context,attrs,defStyle);
    this.ccontext = context;
}

//@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();


    switch (action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) {


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();
            boolean peekingOnly = true;
            final View touchedView = findTopChildUnder((int) x, (int) y);
            if (touchedView != null && touchedView instanceof FrameLayout) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

}

public View findTopChildUnder(int x, int y) {
    final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
    for (int i = childCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final View child = this.getChildAt(i);
        if (x >= child.getLeft() && x < child.getRight() &&
                y >= child.getTop() && y < child.getBottom()) {
            return child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, doing that goes against Android Guidelines.

https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

When the navigation drawer is expanded, the user can dismiss it in one of four ways: **Touching the content outside**, **the navigation drawer Swiping to the left**, **anywhere on the screen (including edge swipe from right)**, **Touching the app icon/title in the action bar**.

Comment: I know, but this is required for my Application

Comment: AFAIK This doesn't support for it